# It seems like basic question......Why OnpropertyChanged doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I am new for learning WPF MVVM ,please help a basic question ,thx.
I use a for-loop to create a counter ,but View doesn't get the property changed.
I know I should use INotifyPropertyChanged to make view refresh ,but it still cannot work...
Why Codes below doesn't work?

View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:DemoVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="321,297,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="38" Width="115" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="98,217,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="560" Value="{Binding Number, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="696,217,26,119" FontSize="20"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
    class DemoVM:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        internal void AddNumber()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Number++;
            }
        }
        int _number;
        public int Number
        {
            get { return _number; }
            set
            {
                _number = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Number));
            }
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DemoVM demoVM = new DemoVM();
            demoVM.AddNumber();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewDesign:
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDDKC.jpg)

Comment: Add this to `Button_Click` event: `DataContext = demoVM;` and before `demoVM.AddNumber();` Or another option you have is get the current view model that is already there, for example: `DemoVM demoVM = DataContext as DemoVM;`

Comment: Do not create a new view model! Use the existing DemoVM object in the DataContext: `DemoVM demoVM = (DemoVM)DataContext;` Do not use the `as` operator when the target type is always DemoVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already have set the binding context of the view to the DemoVM view model, so in your button click, you need not instantiate a new one.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((DemoVM)DataContext).AddNumber();
}
```